# zsh search word in variable behaves strangely

Tags: macos, if-statement, zsh

I'm trying to create a script that checks which Mac's have a **minor** macOS software update available.

I have a strange behavior when searching for two consecutive words in a variable.
It works on some Macs, but not on others. Even though they all have the same macOS version installed.

Specifically, I mean that when this script is executed (and a macOS update is also available, either 13.5.1 or 14.1 is installed on the Macs), it fails on some Macs and says that no macOS update is available. On other Macs this works.

```
#!/bin/zsh

deviceDarwinNum=$(sw_vers | grep BuildVersion | awk {'print $2'} | cut -c1-2)

if [[ 22 == $deviceDarwinNum ]]; then
  echo "macOS Ventura is installed"
  installedmacOSVersion="Ventura"
fi


checkupdate=$(softwareupdate -l 2>&1)

echo $checkupdate

if [[ $checkupdate == *"macOS $installedmacOSVersion"* ]]; then
  echo "==> macOS $installedmacOSVersion software update available <=="

else
  echo "==> NO macOS $installedmacOSVersion software update available <=="
  exit 1
fi
```

The **result**:

```
Script result: macOS Ventura is installed

Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-15.0
    Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 15.0, Size: 721962KiB, Recommended: YES, 
* Label: Safari17.1VenturaAuto-17.1
    Title: Safari, Version: 17.1, Size: 162063KiB, Recommended: YES,
* Label: macOS Ventura 13.6.2-22G320
    Title: macOS Ventura 13.6.2, Version: 13.6.2, Size: 492979KiB, Recommended: YES, Action: restart,  
* Label: macOS Sonoma 14.1.1-23B81
    Title: macOS Sonoma 14.1.1, Version: 14.1.1, Size: 4460818KiB, Recommended: YES, Action: restart, 

==> NO macOS Ventura software update available <==
```

However, the software updatecommand sees that an update is available

I have already replaced the variable *$installedmacOSVersion* with the word "Ventura" (or "Sonoma"), but this does not work either.

I have also tried another if-statement:

```
#!/bin/zsh

deviceDarwinNum=$(sw_vers | grep BuildVersion | awk {'print $2'} | cut -c1-2)

if [[ 22 == $deviceDarwinNum ]]; then
  echo "macOS Ventura is installed"
  installedmacOSVersion="Ventura"
fi


checkupdate=$(softwareupdate -l 2>&1)

echo ""
echo $checkupdate
echo ""

if echo "$checkupdate" | grep -q "macOS $installedmacOSVersion"; then
  echo "==> macOS $installedmacOSVersion software update available <=="

else
  echo "==> NO macOS $installedmacOSVersion software update available <=="
  exit 1
fi
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work with that either.

What am I doing wrong?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I've never used `softwareupdate` and can't spot a problem. I would run the script with `set -x` and verify on the output where things get wrong. You should see the value of the variables and identify the exact statement which does not behave in the expected way.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes might cause problems for `[[ ... ]]` in some cases.

Try this:

```
if [[ $checkupdate == *macOS\ $installedmacOSVersion* ]]; then
```

Comment: I don't think this makes a difference in the concrete case. The difference would matter, if the OP had literal glob characters inside the double quotes.

Comment: unfortunately does not work either :-/

Comment: Can you post zsh (the that works and the one that does not) and macOS version ?